# MYSQL 5.5 Drop Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, quartz.net, alter

I am upgrading my quartz.net version from 1.0.3 to 2.0.2
There is a migration script for database schema, which was was written for MSSQL, and I am trying to write a MYSQL version of it.

However, I haven't been able to drop primary keys (which I need to).

Original MSSQL version of script:

```
ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT BLOB_TRIGGERS_PKEY;
ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT BLOB_TRIGGERS_TRIGGER_NAME_FKEY;
ALTER TABLE SIMPLE_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE SIMPLE_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS_TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE CRON_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_CRON_TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE CRON_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_CRON_TRIGGERS_TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TRIGGERS_JOB_DETAILS;
ALTER TABLE JOB_DETAILS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_JOB_DETAILS;
```

For simplicity, I am trying the first statement there

```
ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP CONSTRAINT BLOB_TRIGGERS_PKEY;
```

Here are what I have tried and results:

- ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP PRIMARY KEY;

> [Err] 1025 - Error on rename of '.\quartz_local#sql-df8_9' to '.\quartz_local\BLOB_TRIGGERS' (errno: 150)

- ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP INDEX 'PRIMARY';

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''PRIMARY'' at line 1

- ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP INDEX `PRIMARY`;

> [Err] 1025 - Error on rename of '.\quartz_local#sql-df8_9' to '.\quartz_local\BLOB_TRIGGERS' (errno: 150)

- ALTER TABLE `BLOB_TRIGGERS` DROP PRIMARY KEY;

> [Err] 1025 - Error on rename of '.\quartz_local#sql-df8_9' to '.\quartz_local\BLOB_TRIGGERS' (errno: 150)

My Mysql version is 5.5.16

EDIT: To check the indexes:
[image: MYSQL Show index results]

EDIT2: Foreign keys on request:
[image: Create table sql]

Comment: `ALTER TABLE BLOB_TRIGGERS DROP PRIMARY KEY;` is syntactically the correct version, so you need to look deepr

Comment: AFAIK, it is. But no luck finding the problem and the solution. What should I be checking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(errno: 150)` is the giveaway: This means Foreign key definition problem. I suspect some other table has a foreign key constraint depending this PK, so you need to drop that first and rebuild it later.

**Edit:** With the images you posted, this becomes clearer:

The FK from BLOBS_TRIGGERS to TRIGGERS is made up from the PK. So if you drop the PK, the contraint becomes stale. You need to drop and later recreate the constraint.

Comment: I confirm there is a foreign key defined in this table pointing to another table.

Comment: I suspect You need to look the other way round: FKs on other tables referencing this table

Comment: I checked it. There is no foreign key constraint pointing to BLOB_CALENDARS table.

Comment: Wasn't his about BLOB_TRIGGERS ?

Comment: Sorry for typo. BLOB_TRIGGERS, indeed.

Comment: However, if I first remove the foreign key pointing from BLOB_TRIGGERS to other tables, then I can remove primary key. Problem is solved, but I don't really get the reason behind.

Comment: You can't have a `FOREIGN KEY` to another table without an index. Your Foreign Key constraint was using the (Primary Key) index.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

After brief Googling, I'm pretty sure the error message is a little misleading. There seem to be a lot of ALTER TABLE statements that might result in that error message.

I'd check to see if there are foreign key references to this table.

Comment: How can I check foreign key references pointing to this table (BLOB_TRIGGERS) ?

Comment: I think you need to [query the KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/key-column-usage-table.html) in information schema views.

Comment: I did and confirmed there is no foreign key pointing to BLOB_TRIGGERS.

Comment: However, if I first remove the foreign key pointing from BLOB_TRIGGERS to other tables, then I can remove primary key. Problem is solved, but I don't really get the reason behind.

Comment: It's not unusual for any SQL dbms to complain when you try to drop something that's involved in a dependency. MySQL just seems to have a suboptimal error message for it. When you try to drop a primary key constraint that's referenced by a foreign key in PostgreSQL, you get an error message that basically says a foreign key depends on the constraint you tried to drop, so use DROP . . . CASCADE to drop dependent objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Deleting foreign keys in the table did not help. There were no other tables referencing the one that had the primary key I was trying to drop. I finally solved the problem by using mysqldump to export the table to an ASCII file. I then edited the file to change the primary key to one I wanted, then I reimported using the mysql command line interface.

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY;